# Use the ASP.NET request user for Log4net log entries

Tags: asp.net, log4net

My ASP.NET site is using Integrated Authentication with impersonation turned off. I have added a "%username" to my "conversionPattern" in the web.config to add the user name to each logging entry. However this will use the application pool identity's user name, and not the current visiting user's name.

Any ideas on how best to do this? Do I have to write a custom appender? I don't mind any minor performance penalties as this is a small intranet site. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative (and easier) solution you may want to take a look at is to use the [`ThreadContext`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.ThreadContext.html) class (formerly implemented as the [`MDC`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.MDC.html) and [`NDC`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.NDC.html) classes). You could have something like this inside an `HttpModule` (before the request arrives at your page) or anywhere else before you log your first message:

```
ThreadContext.Properties["user"] = username;
```

And then include the following in your conversionPattern:

```
%property{user}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've created a HttpModule like you suggested and added that bit of code to the PostAuthorizeRequest event.

Comment: And I've use same code for logging user name, **but there is an problem**: You may initialize log4net with the current user on one thread, then attempt to log on a different thread.

Comment: Do you mean just any other thread or a child thread of the thread you stored a context property in? In the first case, it makes sense that you do not see a user name since this property is thread-local. In the second case you should explicitly set the context property of the child thread.

Answer (score 7):

There's built in ASP.NET pattern converters in recent versions of log4net:

```
%aspnet-request{REMOTE_ADDR} and %aspnet-request{AUTH_USER}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7788792/74585

You can also access the contents of

- aspnet-cache
- aspnet-context
- aspnet-session

https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html