# How to enable IP address logging with Log4Net

Tags: asp.net, logging, log4net

I'm looking a way to enable IP logging with log4net in ASP.NET. I found one [solution](http://marc.info/?l=log4net-user&m=119795169014827&w=2) but it works at Application level. Any suggestions/practices how to log IP at session level?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In `Application_BeginRequest`, do

```
MDC.Set("addr", Request.UserHostAddress);
```

and then ensure that your `PatternLayout` contains `%X{addr}` somewhere in the pattern string.

**Update:** As Tadas has pointed out, in newer versions of log4net the equivalent is

```
ThreadContext.Properties["addr"] = Request.UserHostAddress;
```

coupled with `%P{addr}` in the pattern string.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I just want to note that MDC class is deprecated (http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/site/trunk/docs/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.MDC.html) and forwards to ThreadContext.Properties.

Comment: Nice - I had done this in a previous life, but had forgotten how. +1

Comment: Beware of asp.net 'thread agility' feature : it defeats log4net contexts. See [this blog](http://piers7.blogspot.com/2005/12/log4net-context-problems-with-aspnet.html) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9000825/1178314) on another question for more details.

Answer (score 20):

With log4net 1.2.11 (Oct 2011) you add the following to your pattern layout:

```
%aspnet-request{REMOTE_ADDR}
```

Or for the current user:

```
%aspnet-request{AUTH_USER}
```

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-87 for more info on the new asp.net patterns converters (%aspnet-cache, %aspnet-context, and %aspnet-request).

Comment: Looking at the jira comments, it looks like it lacks support of buffered appenders such as AdoNetAppender, when buffer size is greater than 1. Have you used them with such appenders?