# How to get current username instead of AppPool identity in a logfile with Log4Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, log4net

We are using Log4Net from our ASP.NET MVC3 application, all works fine but we would like to see the current username instead of the application pool's identity in the log files, this is the appender configuration we are using:

```xml
<log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <threshold value="ALL" />
      <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <file value="C:\Logs\MyLogs.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="30" />
      <maximumFileSize value="25MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="[%property{log4net:HostName}] - %username%newline%utcdate - %-5level - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <priority value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

So it seems like the property: `%username` is retrieving the value of:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

Instead of what we would need: `HttpContext.Current.User`

Any idea on how we can solve this easily in the web.config without creating custom properties or additional log4net derived classes? If possible at all otherwise if custom property is the only way we can live with that I guess :) thanks!

Comment: You can get this via an appender pattern in Log4Net version 1.2.11. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26277219/203371

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Replacing `%username` by `%identity` should do it. It is working for me in my current project.

You can learn more about log4net with **[this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial)** excellent tutorial

Comment: No problem :) It's indeed pretty handy!