# How to get Username of Logged in User in Web.Config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, web-config, asp.net-membership, log4net

I want the Username of the User, whose logged in currently. Because I have to give the Name in PatternLayout by using Log4NET.

My Web.Config code for patternLayout is as follows::

```
<log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="App_Data/LOG2.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="{%property{user},level:&quot;%level&quot;,date:&quot;%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}&quot;,message:&quot;%message&quot;}%newline" />

      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

will you Please suggest me what to use instead of `%property{user}`  in ConversionPatters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture username with log4net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813242/capture-username-with-log4net)

Comment: will you please suggest me, How to do this?